# What is the cheapest possible diet that will not cause severe irreversible damage to your health?

Tags: nutrition

Suppose you are locked in a room in New York for three years. You have supply of free drinkable water, utensils for cooking food and access to delivery of groceries from average-priced store. If you have to be able to negate all consequences of your diet, what is the optimal strategy for nutrition aimed at spending as little money as possible?

Comment: Have you made any research based on your question? Because with little or no research, this question is probably opinion based and requires full closure

Comment: asking "what will not ...damage..health" is not opinion based, I think you're missing the specific question here, it's a survival simulation if i understand correctly as well.